# Reimplement QWebView copy link

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, contextmenu, qwebview

I need to reimplement the "copy link" of a `QWebView` in the context menu for doing some other things inside the routine.

The copy link is the only one that really works inside an ajax site so I'm trying to reimplement the "download from link" passing trough this method.

The problem is that I don't know how to reimplement the basic functions of the "copy link" for retrieving the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra menu items by reimplementing [QWebView.contextMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#contextMenuEvent) and generating a standard menu with [QWebPage.createStandardContextMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#createStandardContextMenu).

Then all you need to do is get a [hit-test result](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebhittestresult.html) from the position the context menu was requested from to give you the url (if there is one).

Here's a simple demo of the basic ideas:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtWebKit

class Browser(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.setHtml('''
        <html><head><title>Test Page</title>
        <body>
        <p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a></p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ''')

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = self.page().createStandardContextMenu()
        hit = self.page().currentFrame().hitTestContent(event.pos())
        url = hit.linkUrl()
        if not url.isEmpty():
            menu.addSeparator()
            action = menu.addAction('Download')
            action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.download(url))
        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def download(self, url):
        print('download:', url)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser()
    browser.setGeometry(800, 200, 400, 200)
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! The hit-test result was the part that i missed!